# Netbeans is not deploying my web application

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I have a web application that I have been working on. I recently had to re-image my computer and I have installed the same exact image that my computer was running on before, but the web application will not deploy on the Tomcat 9.0 server through Apache Netbeans 11.1.

I installed the same exact versions of Apache Tomcat 9.0, MySQL 8.0, and Apache Netbeans IDE 11.1 that I was using on the previous image. I have setup all of the same usernames and passwords associated with the Web Server and the MySQL Server.

When I try to deploy the war file through netbeans, it does not start the server and it does not deploy the web application. I can however manually deploy the compiled war file on the Tomcat server and it will work properly.

When I try to deploy the application through the Netbeans IDE, I get the following output.

cd C:\Users*********\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WEBAPPLICATIONNAME; "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2" cmd /c "\"\"C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.1\netbeans\java\maven\bin\mvn.cmd\" -Dnetbeans.deploy=true -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.1\netbeans\java\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 package\""
Scanning for projects...

---

### Building WEBAPPLICATIONNAME1.0-SNAPSHOT

--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:copy (default) @ WEBAPPLICATIONNAME ---

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ WEBAPPLICATIONNAME ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users*********\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WEBAPPLICATIONNAME\src\main\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ WEBAPPLICATIONNAME ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ WEBAPPLICATIONNAME ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users*********\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WEBAPPLICATIONNAME\src\test\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ WEBAPPLICATIONNAME ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ WEBAPPLICATIONNAME ---
No tests to run.

--- maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) @ WEBAPPLICATIONNAME ---
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter (file:/C:/Users/*********/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.3/xstream-1.4.3.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Packaging webapp
Assembling webapp [WEBAPPLICATIONNAME] in [C:\Users*********\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WEBAPPLICATIONNAME\target\WEBAPPLICATIONNAME-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Processing war project
Copying webapp resources [C:\Users*********\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WEBAPPLICATIONNAME\src\main\webapp]
Webapp assembled in [330 msecs]

### Building war: C:\Users*********\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WEBAPPLICATIONNAME\target\WEBAPPLICATIONNAME-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war

### BUILD SUCCESS

Total time: 2.520 s
Finished at: 2019-09-16T16:52:05-06:00

### Final Memory: 12M/47M

Deploying on tomcat90:home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_SERVERNAME
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true

This is the only Output I get from Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

I did some fooling around and realized that I had not selected a deployment server in my project's properties in Netbeans. Right click on your project, click on properties > Run > Server : > Select your Server in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, the main cause on my end was nbactions.xml
add the following under the properties tag

```
  <netbeans.deploy>true</netbeans.deploy>
```