# Run a Maven project on Tomcat from NetBeans

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, netbeans

I have a Maven Java web project opened with NetBeans. The goal is to run and deploy the project on Tomcat from NetBeans by for example clicking on the green play button (like other IDEs).

Should I tweak my maven pom.xml? (All the solution that I could find was related to old NetBeans and Tomcat.)

Comment: I would look at [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) Don't couple anything to your IDE, especially the running of Tomcat, or that will just restrict you

Comment: @g00se : you said that "it is a restriction", but in development phase of any project this is really a handy option. also this functionality has been offered in eclipse and IntelliJ. your link didn't contain any relevant information regarding the config needed to set the enviroment up.

Comment: Well I don't personally work like that and don't use IDEs. Were I using one though, I wouldn't find it inconvenient to switch to a console window and type `mvn deploy:deploy-file` *once*, thereafter using the up/down arrow in the console. I suspect Netbeans is still using Ant in some way, but don't know how that goes with Maven too at the moment. Working out the labyrinthine workings of IDEs is really time wasted. If it's not allowing you to deploy a web app already, I must say that's surprising

Comment: ```mvn deploy:deploy-file```?! Do I need maven plugin for that?

Comment: Yes. Of course I *did* post a link to it... Might be worth looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57965386/netbeans-is-not-deploying-my-web-application) too. In that case, it could be that the deploy plugin is *not* used

Comment: Joachim's answer below addresses your problem, but be aware that when you deploy your app to Tomcat _"a property named "netbeans.hint.deploy.server" is added to your POM"_ by default. There is a workaround for that: _"If for some reason you don’t like the property in the POM, you can move it to the "netbeans-private" profile in the profiles.xml file"._ See the [J2EE Deployment section](https://netbeans.apache.org/wiki/main/wiki/MavenBestPractices/#_j2ee_deployment) of _Best Practices for Apache Maven in NetBeans_ for full details.

Comment: @g00se Yes, coupling your POM to your IDE is not good, and NetBeans will sneakily do that by default when deploying Maven apps to an app server (as mentioned in my previous comment).

Comment: Right. I was quite shocked when I saw what Netbeans did to Ant itself ;)

Answer (score 1):

Open the "Service" view (CTRL+5), right click on the "Servers" node and "Add Server".
After you configured your Tomcat server switch back to the "Projects" view (CTRL+1), open the "Project Properties" (right click on the project root node, then "Properties") and in the category "Run" you can select now the server you just configured and on which the project should get deployed on.
You still need to set your project as the main project ("Run / Set Main Project") and now you can deploy your project with the play button / F6.

NetBeans will create a nb-configuration.xml in the root folder of your project to store those information. You might want to exclude this file from version control. (If you are the only developer there's no harm in including it).